# MonoDevelop window won't shrink

Tags: windows, window, size, monodevelop

The MonoDevelop window will not get any smaller than the screenshot, posted. I am using it on a different computer than I have before (now using Windows 8.1), and have not encountered this problem until now (old computer was on Vista). I tried using Window's "drag to the side and snap to half the screen" feature. All it does is match the height with the screen height. The width remains obnoxiously large. Please, help.

[The smallest that MonoDevelop will go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXqQ0.png)

Comment: I am not sure why this was marked down. I looked all over the internet, and the best I was able to find was a similar question that no one would answer. I realize that it is not a coding-specific inquiry, but the issue is still frustrating and a serious hampering to my workflow. I am sure that I am not the only person who has or will encounter this problem. Please, help, or at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The min. width and height of the Workbench/IDE is:

```
const int MinimumWidth = 800;
const int MinimumHeight = 540;
```

You would need change it in source and re-compile MonoDevelop.

Located in [DefaultWorkbench.cs](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/a7fd52f69188903a1f7d6a9a4748b88f41bc509b/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/DefaultWorkbench.cs)